# Ошибка во время установки Яндекс.Танк

Tags: установка, яндекс-танк

Доброго времени суток. Встретила проблему при установке Яндекс.Танк

```
lipsec@lipsec-H81M-S2PV:~$ sudo apt-get install yandex-load-tank-base
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей  
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Не удалось найти пакет yandex-load-tank-base
lipsec@lipsec-H81M-S2PV:~$ sudo apt-get install yandex-tank
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Не удалось найти пакет yandex-tank
```

Что я делаю не так? 
Сразу оговорюсь, что опыта у меня в этом не очень много.

Answer (score 1):

Deb пакеты теперь deprecated, свежие версии можно взять напрямую из pip или  из докер образа, см. https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

И еще, если у вас в ОС достаточно свежие пакеты зависимостей, можно их поставить из системных пакетов, тогда через pip уже ставить только сам танк,  посмотреть нужные версии можно [в setup.py](https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Разобралась.